# Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 1.0.1 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063

Tags: c#, uwp, signalr

this is the .csproj file of my asp.net core api:
`enter code here`

```
 <PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
 <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Enums\SubCategory.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare" Version="1.1.57" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="12.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

my UWP frontend:
Target version: windows 10, version 1809 (10.0; build 17763)
Min version: Windows 10 Creators update (10.0, build 15063)

I want to create a chat and I want to add aspnetcore signalR client: this is the error I get:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 1.0.1 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063

I have already tried to install different aspnetcore signalR client version, but none of it helps. Could anyone help me with this issue? Thank you

Comment: UWP build 16299 and above supports .NET Standard 2.0 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0/, and then that SignalR package can be used, https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/1.0.1 So in your case, the only hope is to upgrade your UWP runtime.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but apparently I needed to install Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client for the uwp client, and not Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client

Comment: Generally speaking you can use either, as they are equivalent SignalR client libraries. However, the ASP.NET Core version requires .NET Standard 2.0 compliance (I said above that a lower UWP version won't match), while the ASP.NET one only requires .NET Standard 1.3. So you found the solution, but understood it the wrong way.